# Magento 2 : X-Magento-Cache-Debug:MISS, over SSL, pages are not being cached by varnish

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, varnish, apache2, magento

I have configure varnish with magento 2 with the reverse proxy in apache ubuntu.

But, when I see at the headers, I always get the header MISS from the host.

So, page is not being cached by the varnish. Also I have noticed that page speed is decrease after done the reverser proxy to work varnish over SSL 443 port.

When I see the output of the `varnishtop -i BereqURL`, all the accessed pages of website are showing in the list of BereqURL.

For reverse proxy I have added below code in `my-ssl.conf`

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass               / http://127.0.0.1:80/
ProxyPassReverse        / http://127.0.0.1:80/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

So do I need to add any other header for vanish start caching the all pages?

Can anyone help me with this issue?